# iOS SDK : How to draw Line Chart with marker using Google Chart API

Tags: objective-c, ipad, google-visualization, xcode4.5

I am trying to draw Line chart with Google Chart API on iPad like the one shown below :

[image]

I am able to draw a simple chart with following URL :

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:%7CJan%7CFeb%7CMar%7CJun%7CJul%7CAug%7C1:%7C10%7C20%7C30%7C40%7C50&chxt=x,y&chs=600x400&cht=lc&chd=t:22,3,89,54,65,45&chg=25,50&chls=0.75,-1,-1%7C2,4,1&chm=o,FF9900,1,-2,8%7Cb,3399CC44,0,1,0
```

Now I need to show marker like the one shown in the figure below where X and Y intersects.

How can I implement the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to do the same. Posting the link for reference.

For symbolic notation :

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:%7CJan%7CFeb%7CMar%7CJun%7CJul%7CAug%7C1:%7C100%7C50%7C0&chf=bg,s,CCFFCC&cht=lc&chs=600x400&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:%7CTimeJan%7CFeb%7CMarch%7CApril%7CMay%7CJune%7CJuly%7C1:%7C0%7C10%7C20%7C30%7C40%7C50%7C60%7C70%7C80%7C90%7C100%7CScore&chd=t:20,50,70,90,45,50,80&chg=18,20&chdl=Score&chm=o,000000,0,-1,10.0
```

For Numeric Value refer the below one :

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxl=0:%7CJan%7CFeb%7CMar%7CJun%7CJul%7CAug%7C1:%7C100%7C50%7C0&chf=bg,s,CCFFCC&cht=lc&chs=600x400&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:%7CTimeJan%7CFeb%7CMarch%7CApril%7CMay%7CJune%7CJuly%7C1:%7C0%7C10%7C20%7C30%7C40%7C50%7C60%7C70%7C80%7C90%7C100%7CScore&chd=t:20,50,70,90,45,50,80&chg=18,20&chdl=Score&chm=N,000000,0,-1,10.0
```